# How would I add 1 to the first value in memory and store the value in the adjacent word, and also place a copy of this value in register $v0

Tags: mips

.data
A:  .word   0xcafebeee

.text
#Your code goes here

- How would I write code to add 1 the first value in memory, which will be found at 0x1001000
  Store this value in the adjacent word, and also place a copy of this value in register $v0

-By default, the value 0xcafebee will be placed at address 0x1001000. Your program must add 1 to the value found at address 0x1001000. For example 0xcafebeee incremented by 1 is the value 0xcafebeef. This answer will be placed in two places:
the adjacent word space, and in register $v0.Do NOT change the .data segment. All of your work MUST be contained in .text

-What a successful ouput looks like: https://content.screencast.com/users/profbsmith/folders/Snagit/media/34becefb-ed96-4c23-8bbc-69b3181c63cc/10.28.2020-09.17.png

Comment: This looks a bit like a homework assignmet to me.  Also, what you describe is decidedly not C.  It's a specific embedded compiler's interpretation of C, as indicated by the assumption of an initial value at address 0x1001000 and the idea of copying a value into register $v0.  C has no inherent concept of registers, but some compilers do offer extensions to do things like this.  Also, data and text segments is an assembly language concept.

Comment: It's assembly language (MIPS)

Comment: I have updated the tags to reflect this.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: I've done MIPS assembly in the past, but its not an assignment that I'm undertaking.  It looks like your professor is trying to teach you how to do something with this exercise.

Answer (score 0):

.data
A:  .word   0xcafebeee

.text
#Your code goes here

```
    la $t1,A        
    lw $t2,0($t1)    
    addi $t2,$t2,1  
    
    addi $t1,$t1,4  
    sw $t2,0($t1)   
    
    move $v0,$t2
```